# Swift 3D rotation of UIImageView (CGAffineTransform or CATransform3D)

Tags: swift, cgaffinetransform, catransform3d

I have an image that I want to rotate, about its centre point, in 3D depending on the roll/pitch/yaw of the iPhone.

Which is the preferred solution: CGAffineTransform or CATransform3D?

Are there any examples I can follow. There are numerous posts that allude towards a solution.

The image for simplicity's sake the image is a rectangle.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CoreMotion gives device's current attitude (with yaw, pitch ,roll, in eulerian mode or as quaternion rotation). These are 3 different ways to express the same thing.
What you need to do is to apply the transformations correctly to reflect the device's current attitude.
Consider this sample.

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var rect1: UIView! // Add background color to be ale to see it
    @IBOutlet weak var rect2: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var xLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var yLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var zLabel: UILabel!


    let motionManager = CMMotionManager() // The one and only for the app

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //The device motion object provides the device orientation in several equivalent forms: Euler angles, a rotation matrix, and a quaternion. Since we already use matrices to represent rotations in our Metal code, they are they best fit for incorporating Core Motion’s data into our app.
        let motionHandler: CMDeviceMotionHandler = { [weak self] (motion, error)  in
            if let err = error { print(err) }
            if let m = motion {
                self?.xLabel.text = "Yaw: \(m.attitude.yaw)"
                self?.yLabel.text = "Pitch: \(m.attitude.pitch)"
                self?.zLabel.text = "Roll: \(m.attitude.roll)"

                var transform: CATransform3D

                transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(m.attitude.pitch), 1, 0, 0) // X rotation
                transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(m.attitude.roll), 0, 1, 0) // Y rotation
                transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(m.attitude.yaw), 0, 0, 1) // Z rotation
                print(transform)

                self?.rect1.layer.transform = transform
                // Mind coordinate space is most intuitive. The following transform differs.
                // If you can tell why - please do.
                let rm = m.attitude.rotationMatrix

                transform = CATransform3D(m11: CGFloat(rm.m11), m12: CGFloat(rm.m12), m13: CGFloat(rm.m13), m14: 0,
                                          m21: CGFloat(rm.m21), m22: CGFloat(rm.m22), m23: CGFloat(rm.m23), m24: 0,
                                          m31: CGFloat(rm.m31), m32: CGFloat(rm.m32), m33: CGFloat(rm.m33), m34: 0,
                                          m41: 0,               m42: 0,               m43: 0,               m44: 1)
                print(transform)


                self?.rect2.layer.transform = transform
                //self?.compass.layer.sublayerTransform = transform
                //[myImage setNeedsDisplay];
            }
        }
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1

        if let current = OperationQueue.current {
            motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical/*.xTrueNorthZVertical*/, to: current, withHandler: motionHandler)
        }

    }
}
```

To reproduce it is necessary to create UIViews (`rect1`, `rect2`) in the Storyboard, hook them up to the viewController. As you rotate the device, these views will be transformed accordingly. You may try CMQuaternion (`m.attitude.quaternion`) to do similar job.